# Haskell function signature confusion

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to learn Haskell, but I'm stumped on something. So far, I've come to understand that functions signatures conform to this convention:

```
<name> :: <type constraint A> => <input type A> -> <input type B> -> .. <input type X> -> <return type>
```

So, some examples with my current understanding are:

```
-- Returns input + 2
add2 :: Int -> Int
add2 x = x + 2

-- Returns the result of applying a function that takes an int and returns an int on an input int
adds2 :: (Int -> Int) -> Int -> Int
adds2 func x = func x

-- Returns a String with "Hello" prepended to the front
sayHello :: String -> String
sayHello name = "Hello " ++ name
```

Then I came across this which is what stumped me:

```
mate :: RandomGen g => Gene -> Gene -> Rand g Gene
```

I understand that the functions name is `mate`, and it has a type constraint where the `g` must be of type `RandomGen`, it then takes as input two values of type `Gene`.

However, it is the return type that is really confusing me. How do you interpret this and could anyone explain it to a novice Haskeller?

Comment: Your description looks correct. For the last type, note that `Rand g Gene` is a monadic type, obtained by applying the monad `Rand g` to the type `Gene`. If you are not yet familiar with monads, it will be not easy to fully understand the consequences. Still, in English, a value of `Rand g Gene` is a description of a computation which is able to read and write a RNG state variable of type `g`, and produce a `Gene` value as a result. More succinctly, `mate` returns a `Gene`, but the result is random, so it's not a regular deterministic function..

Comment: Ah, the dreaded monad.... Everytime I've tried to get stuck in to Haskell I hit this "Monad" wall, all the resources I've read I get close to grasping the concept but it never seems to click :-(

Comment: You don't actually need to know *anything* about Monads to understand the type signature. All you need to know is that `Rand` is a "type constructor" that takes 2 parameters to make a "concrete" type. Technically we say that `Rand` is a type whose "kind" is `* -> * -> *` (which you'll also see written as `Type -> Type -> Type`), which is completely analogous to a function having type `a -> b -> c` - it's a "function of types" which takes 2 types and produces another one. `Maybe` is a simple example which you probably know about already - this has kind `* -> *` (it takes 1 type parameter).

Comment: Read the constraint as "`g` has to have an *instance* of the typeclass `RandomGen`".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you defined yourself a data type like

```
data MyType = A Int String
```

then `A`, your data constructor, would effectively be a function with type

```
A :: Int -> String -> MyType
```

and you'd call it like this to produce a value of `MyType`.

```
A 42 "hello"
```

So that's data constructors.

Haskell also has type constructors. `Rand` is one. Just like function values have function types that define how they can be applied, type constructors have "function" *kinds* that determine how they can be applied. The kind of a regular old type like `Int` or `String` is spelled `*`. The kind of `Rand`, which is a type constructor, is `* -> * -> *`: it takes two types and produces a type from those.

So when you apply `Rand` to types `g` and `Gene`, you get the return type of your function, which is `Rand g Gene`.

For more, see [this chapter of Learn You A Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses#type-parameters).

("Okay, but... what is a `Rand g Gene`?", I hear you ask. Well, assuming you mean [this `Rand`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/MonadRandom-0.5.1.1/docs/Control-Monad-Random-Lazy.html#t:Rand), `Rand g Gene` is a value that represents a computation that would produce a `Gene` if you run it in something that is capable of running `Rand g` things, such as [`runRand`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/MonadRandom-0.5.1.1/docs/Control-Monad-Random-Lazy.html#v:runRand). Now, that's not the only thing you can do with a `Rand g Gene`, because it so happens `Rand g` is a... *dun dun dun*... monad! For a lot more on that concept, you really should read something like [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/a-fistful-of-monads)... there are a lot of preliminaries to get through to explain it in full to a newbie.)

Comment: So does that mean the return type of this function is itself a function that takes a Rand and a g and returns a Gene? If so, would it not make more sense to declare the function like so:

`mate :: RandomGen g => Gene -> Gene -> (Rand -> g -> Gene)`

Comment: Or is a `kind` a higher order abstraction than `type`? In the normal vernacular a kind is a synonym of a type no? Like a spoon is a kind of cutlery but a spoon is also a type of cutlery no?

Comment: Have you worked with `Maybe` yet? `Maybe` is a type constructor, so `Maybe Int` is a valid type, but so is `Maybe String`. `Rand` is the same thing; it's just taking two parameters instead of the one `Maybe` takes.

Comment: @ThomasCook It's more like `mate :: RandomGen g => Gene -> Gene -> (g -> (g, Gene))`, up to some `newtype` wrappers. I.e. take the old RNG seed `g`, and output the next seed along with the `Gene` result. Perhaps this is not the easiest monad to understand as the first one.

Comment: In Haskell, value-level things have types, and type-level things have kinds. (They have English synonyms because they're very analogous concepts.) So if you're wondering what variety of beast `42`, a value, is, you would answer that it is a value of type `Int`. And if you're wondering what variety of beast `Int`, a type, is, you would answer that it is a type of kind `*`.

Comment: Hmm, well actually (g -> (g, Gene)) makes a hell of a lot more sense than Rand g Gene  to me, so if that's a legitimate way to think of it I'll build my understanding of the Monad from that.

On that point, isn't a Monad a concept you understand once and it applies to all Monads? Or is a Monad a term for something that has several different meanings depending on context?

Comment: So, @user11228628 - is it helpful to think of kinds as a higher order of types?

Comment: You understand monads once in the same way you understand objects once. Once you know what an object is (in, say, Java), it's way easier to program with them, but each individual object still has its own quirks you need to learn. Likewise, once you grok monads, they start to come naturally, but each type of monad still has its own idiosyncrasies.

Comment: Yea I need to just smash through this brick wall that is my mental block on understanding this. Can someone re-affirm me that it's worth the mental effort to do so?

Comment: Haha I know, pathetic, it's just been bugging me that I don't understand monads for so long now.

Comment: It is absolutely worth it. I started learning Haskell five years ago and I still wouldn't necessarily call myself an expert. I didn't have a firm understanding of monads until at least a year into learning. You're not behind the curve; this is normal, and once you get it it will improve your programming so much, not just in Haskell but in every language.

Comment: I use RX every day at work and as I understand it that also has Monads, so I'm used to using flatMap, map, switchMap, merge, zip and other such operators in RX (Java) - do you think there is anyway I can conceptualize Monads based on my RX Java experience?

Comment: Loosely, `map` corresponds to Haskell's `fmap` and `flatMap` should correspond to the monadic bind `>>=`. Can't speak for the others, as I haven't used RX (`flatMap` is a name in Scala so I'm assuming it does the same thing in RX). That said, learning to leverage do-notation is something that doesn't really have an equivalent in other languages. It's just syntax sugar, but it's very handy. However, that is something that can come later, as the priority is understanding how to use monads, not how to look pretty using them.

Comment: You'll be able to use RX observables as an *example* of a monad. And having some familiarity with `map` and `flatMap` in particular will be useful in understanding  how the generalizations of those functions work in other monads. But I think Silvio's analogy was spot on: the concept *monad* is like the concept *class* —examples are everywhere, and understanding what the concept is may require building intuition from a lot of specific examples.

Comment: Thanks peeps, I'll keep chipping away at it till it makes sense :-)

Comment: I've now opened this question to try and understand how types relate to kinds:

https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/111430/whats-the-difference-between-a-type-and-a-kind